# How to restore perforce from version files?

Tags: perforce, restore

I tryed migrate from perforce 2005 to 2010 and failed. I created checkpoint and journal files (with p4d -jc command), copy version files on old machine. But failed restore it on new machine. On first try i get
"Journal file 'journal' replay failed at line 9680!
Bad opcode '' journal record!"
error. I found in journal file zero bytes and remove it. On second try I get error:
"Perforce server error
1 out of sequence journals were not replayed"

What do next? How to repair journal file? Can I restore Perforce database without journal file using only version files?

P.S. Perforce still work on old machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your journal got corrupted at some point. Since perforce is still running on the old machine I suggest you to start the migration over ensuring at each step that nothing got corrupted. For instance look at the journal size after generation, or better make a md5 or an sha1 of it, and check everything is still ok on the new machine. Also ensure that p4d is stopped before copying any file.

Since you upgrade from p4 2005 to p4 2010 you probably have a specific procedure, did you follow it?

Comment: gabuzo, thank you for your answer. I solved the problem. 1) I regenerated journal file on old machine. 2) I used correct "current" journal file. (just "journal" not "journal.n") 3) I upgraded database with "p4d -xu" command.